# Is it possible to run multiple instance of skype?

Tags: windows-7, skype, multiple-instances

At the moment when run, I can only open one instance of skype. Is it possible to do so with 2 instances?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found it myself but forgot the site where I learned this, sorry :(

Run skype application from command line with argument `/secondary`

E.g.

In my case I executed `"C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" /secondary`

Comment: https://support.skype.com/en/faq/fa829/how-can-i-run-two-skype-accounts-on-the-same-computer

Comment: For easiness, create a new shortcut with the above said location and switch; name it as skype secondary or something else. so that no need of typing this whole thing again and again.

Comment: The new Version dose not have that file?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, run the first one on your computer and run the second one using the portable apps version:

http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/skype_portable

Comment: Cool idea, and darned simple.

Comment: As of today, this doesn't work. The portable version reports that another instance is running and refuses to start no matter what.

Comment: I blame Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

Though it's been answered, I thought of providing a cool answer here. MultiSkype launcher is the best solution to your problem. It's a free software which you can install on Windows operating system. By running the software you can add multiple Skype accounts with passwords and finally you have to select which account to open and run. That's it. I have tried four accounts with this application. You can use more than that I guess. I have logged in to four Skype accounts simultaneously and have worked without any problem. You can go to the [MultiSkype](http://multi-skype-launcher.com/) launcher website [here](http://multi-skype-launcher.com/) and you can see the download link there. No need to download portable apps or go and run the Skype separately. This will do it.

Answer (score 1):

At least with earlier versions, I had luck by creating multiple skype.exe executeable copies and then running them in different user contexts using XP's "fast user switching" feature.

In that szenario, user A autostarted one copy of the executeable, and user B autostarted a different one. Both users logged in simultaneously. Both of them could use Skype. There were problems, of course, when one user session with an active Skype talk was switched away, and the other user tried to use Skype for communication. Everything else worked fine, if I remember correctly.

And note that in my scenario, both users had their own desktops. I am not sure if it would be enough to use RunAs or a similar run-command-as-a-different-user utility.

The good thing is if this works with the current Skype version, it will work for more than two users, too (as apposed to the portable variant suggestion).